# git commit: cannot read lockfile

Tags: git, github, commit, git-commit, gnupg

I tried installing gpg and bumped into some error while trying to commit to GitHub.

After battling with the error I was getting I had to uninstall Kleopatra from my system, but I noticed windows command prompt couldn't find the gpg path anymore.

However, `git bash` was still seeing it and I keep getting same commit error and I don't know what to do since I have tried some solutions I found here.

Here is my error when I try to use GitHub desktop same goes with git bash

```
error: cannot spawn C:\Program: No such file or directory
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

[image: error]

Comment: I believe the issue you're encountering is because you uninstalled Kleopatra. First, I would reinstall it. Second, it seems GitHub Desktop is trying to launch `C:\Programs` which is an invalid path for gpg. Git Bash actually comes with its own install of gpg, which is why it's still available there (type `which gpg` to see what path it's using). What was the error you were getting that prompted you to uninstall Kleopatra?

Comment: gpg: invalid size of lockfile 'C:\Users\Kelvin Obidozie\AppData\Roaming\gnupg/pubring.kbx.lock'
gpg: cannot read lockfile
gpg: can't lock 'C:\Users\Kelvin Obidozie\AppData\Roaming\gnupg/pubring.kbx'
gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...
gpg: can't open 'where'

this is the error that prompted me to delete the kleopatra

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a setting involving a path with a space, without being with quotes for [Gpg4win](https://www.file.net/process/kleopatra.exe.html)

```
C:\Prgram Files\Gpg4win\bin\kleopatra.exe
```

Check you [`git config --global gpg.program`](https://gist.github.com/BoGnY/f9b1be6393234537c3e247f33e74094a?permalink_comment_id=2718488#gistcomment-2718488=) value, for such a path.

As noted by the [OP Kelvin Obidozie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19609210/kelvin-obidozie) in the comments:

> I fixed it.
>
> I created a new one and followed the instructions on this site "[Configure GPG to sign Git commits (in Windows)](https://neurotechnics.com/blog/configure-gpg-to-sign-git-commits-in-windows/)" from  , but placed my directory in double quotes and left it with the default forward slash.
>
> I also noticed that all the while I've been trying to create the key it kept adding new instances like so (`C:\\Program`) so I deleted all of it and placed the correct one ("`C:/Program Files/GnuPG/bin/gpg.exe`") in double quotes and I finally pushed my commit to GitHub.
> It worked like a charm.

```
[gpg]
        program = "C:/Program Files/GnuPG/bin/gpg.exe"
```

Comment: when i run the check command what comes up is the C:\Programs and when I run which gpg this is what comes up /usr/bin/gpg

Comment: I fixed it. I created a new one and followed the instructions on this site [https://neurotechnics.com/blog/configure-gpg-to-sign-git-commits-in-windows/] but placed my directory in double quotes and left it with the default forward slash.

I also noticed that all the while I've been trying to create the key it kept adding new instances like so (C:\\Program) so I deleted all of it and placed the correct one ("C:/Program Files/GnuPG/bin/gpg.exe")in double quotes and I finally pushed my commit to GitHub. It worked like a charm.. thanks for the assist.

Comment: @KelvinObidozie Well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. Can you edit it to include your final global `.gitconfig` file, with its gpg directive?

Comment: yes, you can. that's how I configured the path correctly using the .gitconfig file

Comment: @KelvinObidozie I meant, can you copy-paste the exact gpg line you have in your `.gitconfig`?

Comment: program = "C:/Program Files/GnuPG/bin/gpg.exe"